# This fake notification should be forwarded to firebase Swift5 iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have gone through the official notification and followed all steps. Also APN certificates are already uploaded on firebase. When i push notifciation from Grow section manually, i receive notification but while while entering phone number with country code in my app, i am getting the following errors.

**This fake notification should be forwarded to Firebase Auth**

> **Optional(Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17054 "If app delegate swizzling is disabled, remote notifications received by
>   UIApplicationDelegate need to be forwarded to FIRAuth's
>   canHandleNotificaton: method." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=If app
>   delegate swizzling is disabled, remote notifications received by
>   UIApplicationDelegate need to be forwarded to FIRAuth's
>   canHandleNotificaton: method.,
>   FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_NOTIFICATION_NOT_FORWARDED})**

In Google `info.plist`, `isfirebaseProxyEnable` is also set to No.

`DidreceiveRemoteNotification` method also implemented.

Please help me in solving this problem.

Comment: Hey were you able to solve this? I am stuck with the same. How did you get the detailed error . I am only getting the fake notification part in the logs.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't have APNs set up correctly, check that:

1. **Push notifications** is enabled in **Capabilities** of your app in
   Xcode settings.
2. **Background Modes** is enabled in **Capabilities** of
   your app in Xcode settings and under it **Remote notifications** is
   checked
3. Your app ID registered on apple developer site has **Push Notification** enabled
4. **Background refresh** is not disabled on the device or for your app in iOS
   Settings

I assume that you have an internet connection during the tests.

If any points of the above need to change, just delete the app completely from the device before re-compile and run it again.

Comment: step 3 , what is PN enabled ?

Comment: @Khodour.F Probably "push notification"

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, make sure you have this function in you AppDelegate file:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification notification: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if Auth.auth().canHandleNotification(notification) {
        completionHandler(.noData)
        return
    }
}
```